# How to get the points inside of the ellipse in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to identify the densest region in the plot. And I do this using `stat_ellipse()` in ggplot2. But I can not get the information (sum total, order number of each point and so on) of the points inside of the ellipse.

Seldom see the discussion about this problem. Is this possible?

For example:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions))+
    geom_point()+
    stat_ellipse()
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to calculate the ellipse outside ggplot and use some sort of a function that will identify points inside/outside. `sp::over` is one, `sp::point.in.polygon` another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is Roman's suggestion implemented. The help for `stat_ellipse` says it uses a *modified* version of `car::ellipse`, so therefore I chose to extract the ellipse points from the `ggplot` object. That way it should always be correct (also if you change options in `stat_ellipse`).

```
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)

# Build the plot first
p <- ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse()

# Extract components
build <- ggplot_build(p)$data
points <- build[[1]]
ell <- build[[2]]

# Find which points are inside the ellipse, and add this to the data
dat <- data.frame(
  points[1:2], 
  in.ell = as.logical(point.in.polygon(points$x, points$y, ell$x, ell$y))
)

# Plot the result
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = in.ell)) +
  stat_ellipse()
```

[image]