# extract points/data within ellipse ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ellipse, ggforce

I am using `geom_ellipse` to create an ellipse on `faithful` dataset.
Here is the code:

```
t <- position_nudge(x=-1,y=-0.5)

obj <- ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions))+
  geom_point()+ geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 70, y0 = 3, a= 3, b = 10,angle = pi/3),color="red",
                             position = t)
```

The graph looks like this:
[image: ellipse]

I want to extract the points/data that are present within the ellipse? How can I do that? I tried what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650441/how-to-get-the-points-inside-of-the-ellipse-in-ggplot2) , but it does not work for geom_ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with `geom_ellipse` is that when you look at the data of the layer with `ggplot_build`, you can see that the ellipse is shown multiple times in a data loop. So what you could do is get a first copy of the values like 272 values (same as your data). Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650441/how-to-get-the-points-inside-of-the-ellipse-in-ggplot2) you can do the following:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(sp)
t <- position_nudge(x=-1,y=-0.5)
obj <- ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions))+
  geom_point()+ geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 70, y0 = 3, a= 3, b = 10,angle = pi/3),color="red",
                             position = t)
obj
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
```

[image]

```r
# Extract components
build <- ggplot_build(obj)$data
points <- build[[1]]
ell <- build[[2]]

# Find which points are inside the ellipse, and add this to the data
dat <- data.frame(
  points[1:2], 
  in.ell = as.logical(point.in.polygon(points$x, points$y, ell$x[1:272], ell$y[1:272]))
)

# Plot the result
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = in.ell)) +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 70, y0 = 3, a= 3, b = 10,angle = pi/3),color="red",
               position = t)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

When you check the `dat` dataframe, you can see which points are in the ellipse.

Comment: This works great for the above example!!. I have another data set with lot's of points within the ellipse and in total around 11000 points in the input file. When I use `ell$x[1:11000]`, it actually doesn't produce true points in ellipse, but when I played with it, `ell$x[1:400]` worked. Any reason you can think of why that happens?

Comment: Hi @user3138373, great to hear it worked! Probably the values are somehow randomly sampled. The thing is that you should at least have a certain amount of samples of your ellipse so that you can classify the points. I would recommend you to check if the 400 points almost fully describe the ellipse to make sure you classify it correctly.