# Pulling out Outlier Data from PCA in R

Tags: r, outliers, genomics

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCqfb.png) I created a PCA chart on r using the code below, but I want to pull the data from the outliers (anything outside my circle), out so that I can compare their data. If anyone could help out with how I would code to pull that info out it would be helpful!

I used this code and have the chart attached, so everything looks right here I just dont know how to pull out only the outlier data.

```
library(vcfR)
library(poppr)
library(ape)
library(RColorBrewer)

#load in file and validate
rubi.VCF <- read.vcfR("//Users/myname/Downloads/not.vcf")
rubi.VCF

gl.rubi <- vcfR2genlight(rubi.VCF)
ploidy(gl.rubi) <- 2
gl.rubi

rubi.pca <- glPca(gl.rubi, nf = 3)
barplot(100*rubi.pca$eig/sum(rubi.pca$eig), col = heat.colors(50), main="PCA Eigenvalues")
title(ylab="Percent of variance\nexplained", line = 2)
title(xlab="Eigenvalues", line = 1)

rubi.pca.scores <- as.data.frame(rubi.pca$scores)
rubi.pca.scores$pop <- pop(gl.rubi)

library(ggplot2)
set.seed(9)
p <- ggplot(rubi.pca.scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2) )
p <- p + geom_point(size=2)
p <- p + stat_ellipse(level = 0.95, size = 1)
#p <- p + scale_color_manual(values = cols) 
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = 0) 
p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) 
p <- p + theme_bw()

p
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Since this only seems to involve the data in the plot, we don't really need all the code before the plot. Just include the data from `rubi.pca.scores` as a `dput()` to make it reproducible.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650441/how-to-get-the-points-inside-of-the-ellipse-in-ggplot2) should help.